# Executing a python script in Google Compute Engine from App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I have a Python script stored in a Compute Engine instance. I also have a web application deployed on the Google App Engine.

What I would like to achieve is let users enter some parameters on the web application interface and have it execute the script in the Compute Engine instance with the entered parameters.

My question is: how can I access the Compute Engine instance from App Engine and execute the script with the parameters that users passed in?

Comment: There are several methods. What you have you tried? Your question lacks detail on exactly what you want to do, the resources required, etc., so an answer is hard to generate. Look into 1) Building a REST interface running on Compute Engine (simple and this is what I would do). Flask makes this simple as an example. 2) Use a Python SSH library and execute the script in an SSH session.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several factors here to take into account:

- Security implications: Having a web site backend accessing a different host to run a command with client-defined parameters upon a request can easily introduce lots of potential exploits that aren't worth dealing with.
- Sanitizing the parameter or parameters from the Python script would be a must, which you might be able to do this with [shlex.quote()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote).
- Running the script in the VM instance via SSH from App Engine:

  - With the [Google Cloud Client Library for Python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python#google-cloud-python-client) you may be able to connect to a given GCE instance and run a command by [setting up OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access) and granting [roles/compute.osLogin](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.osLogin) for this instance to the Service Account that runs your App Engine app as described in [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/service-account-ssh#sa_ssh) (with [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/compute/oslogin)).
  - Otherwise, you may try creating a system account for this purpose inside the instance and allow its login in its `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and use a new RSA key added to this user's `~/ssh/.authorized_keys` file with a generic SSH client library like [Paramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/) connecting to its external IP address, assuming it has one.
  - In both cases this is going to introduce very high latencies for the requests as SSH sessions usually take 2+ seconds to get created.
- As an acceptable-latency (and potentially more secure) alternative, you might be able to have a simple HTTPS service in the VM (you can probably check for a correct snakeoil certificate in your Python code if needed) and set up a [webhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook) with a long hash-like URL path (and optionally a non-default port) handled by, for instance, a simple PHP script that runs the end script with [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) after passing the parameter variable in its `$_POST[]` superglobal through [excapeshellarg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to (re-)sanitize it.